# Cake PHP Save Associated record only when data exists

Tags: php, cakephp

i am currently learning Cake PHP and have encountered a bit of a problem i cant seem to overcome. If anyone could offer any advice it would be appreciated.

For the purpose of my question i have two tables: tenants and sub_tenants.

Here is my tenants model:

```
// app/Model/Tenant.php
class Tenant extends AppModel {
 public $hasMany = 'SubTenants';
}
```

I have a form in my view that allows one tenant and up to four sub tenants to be entered all together. This is my view: (additional non relevant code omitted to simplify)

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->create('Tenant'); ?> 

 <?php echo $this->Form->input('full_name') ?>
 <?php echo $this->Form->input('email') ?>

 <?php echo $this->Form->input('SubTenants.0.full_name', array('label' => 'Full Name')) ?>
 <?php echo $this->Form->input('SubTenants.0.email', array('label' => 'Full Name')) ?>

 <?php echo $this->Form->input('SubTenants.1.full_name', array('label' => 'Full Name')) ?>
 <?php echo $this->Form->input('SubTenants.1.email', array('label' => 'Full Name')) ?>

 <?php echo $this->Form->input('SubTenants.2.full_name', array('label' => 'Full Name')) ?>
 <?php echo $this->Form->input('SubTenants.2.email', array('label' => 'Full Name')) ?>

 <?php echo $this->Form->input('SubTenants.3.full_name', array('label' => 'Full Name')) ?>
 <?php echo $this->Form->input('SubTenants.3.email', array('label' => 'Full Name')) ?>
 <?php echo $this->Form->end()?>
```

In the tenants controller i then save this data using saveAssociated like so:

```
public function new_tenant() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Tenant->saveAssociated($this->request->data);
        }   
    }
```

This works fine as long as all four sub tenants forms are completed; however i need the sub tenants data to be optional and/or variable (there might be less than four sub tenants at times)

Could anyone advise me as to how i can go about this, is it possible to do this using saveAssociated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$hasMany = 'SubTenants'` => why plural suddently? The models are always singular. So it should be SubTenant for consistency. Also: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave your code as it is and try to save subtenant 1 and 4, you'll get validation errors in 2 and 3 (if you have a "notEmpty" rule, for example). If you don't have validations in the SubTenant model, you'll be saving all subtenants (1 thru 4), but 2 and 3 will be null.

So you have to change your code.

```
public function new_tenant() {
   if ($this->request->is('post')) {
       $subsToSave = array();
       foreach ($this->request->data['SubTenants'] as $index => $subtenant) {
          if ($subtenant['fullname'] != '' && $subtenant['email'] != '')
            $subsToSave[] = $subtenant;
       }
       $this->Tenant->saveAssociated(array('SubTenants'=>$subsToSave));
   }
}
```

But that way the data validation is not guaranteed to fall on the same subject. For example, if you fill subtenant 1 and 4, and you put a number on both names (let's say you have a data validation that doesn't accept numbers on names), then with the second code, the form errors will probably fall on subtenant 1 and 2 in the view.

Well, either way, be sure to catch the errors on save, don't leave a `$this->Tenant->saveAssociated($this->request->data);` all alone there, what happens if there's a save error, are you going to let it pass and not warn the user?